# Yet another sequence point query: how does *p++ = getchar() work?

Tags: c, sequence-points

[§5.1.2.4.16](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> EXAMPLE 7 The grouping of an expression does not completely determine its evaluation. In the following fragment:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int sum;
> char *p;
> /*
> ...
> */
> sum = sum * 10 - '0' + (*p++ = getchar());
> ```
>
> the expression statement is grouped as if it were written as
>
> ```
> sum = (((sum * 10) - '0') + ((*(p++)) = (getchar())));
> ```
>
> but the actual increment of p can occur at any time between the previous sequence point and the next sequence point (the ; ), and the call to getchar can occur at any point prior to the need of its returned value.

So basically I understand this as *unspecified behavior* - either `*p = getchar(); p++;` OR `p++; *p = getchar()`. Note that the `;` implies a sequence point, but there are no other sequence points in the whole expression.

So this syntax is useless. And, pretty much, ++ and -- for pointer assignment is useless. *Right?*

Comment: It doesn't matter when the `p++` post-increment happens, because p is only evaluated once in the expression.

Comment: in `(*p++ = getchar())` , the `p++` is only a side effect, `p` is never referenced at a second place in the same statement, so `p++` *cannot* cause sequence point errors. (except if it would point to `sum`, or somewhere inside the buffer of the stdin FILE)

Comment: change `p* = getchar()` to `*p = getchar()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> either `*p = getchar(); p++;` OR `p++; p* = getchar()` [[sic]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)

Well actuall no. It's either:

```
*p = getchar(); p++
```

or

```
old_p = p++; *old_p = getchar()
```

In your interpretation, you could either write at `*p` or `*(p + 1)` which is not true. In both interpretations, you write to where `p` originally pointed to, regardless of when the compiler decides to put the instruction that changes `p`. If it decides to put it before the write to `*p`, then it would have to make sure it keeps the old value to later write to (`*old_p`).

The suffix `--` and `++` operators are actually quite nice shortcuts. Take this example:

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while (str[len++]);
    return len - 1;
}
```

This is a very concise implementation of `strlen` using suffix `++`.

---

From C11, 6.5.2.4.2 (emphasis mine):

> **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand**. As a side effect, the
>    value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
>   added to it). See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
>   information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on
>   pointers. **The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of
>   updating the stored value of the operand.** With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced
>   function call, the operation of postfix ++ is a single evaluation. Postfix ++ on an object
>      with atomic type is a read-modify-write operation with memory_order_seq_cst
>     memory order semantics.

Comment: Sounds like there is some rule that postfix operators take effect after the **expression** finishes. This is puzzling. The standard says "all side effects have to be completed until the next sequence point". But here it seems to be a requirement that ++ is applied **after** some event. What event?

Comment: You should `return len-1;` Imagine what would happen in the case of  the empty string `""` as the `str` argument.

Comment: @Vorac: there is no such rule. Please believe Shahbaz when he tells you that the value of `p++` is the old value of `p`. It does not matter when `p` is modified, because the old value is the same either way, and so `*p++` refers to the same `char` regardless of when `p` is incremented.

Comment: "sounds like there is some rule that postfix operators take effect after the expression finishes" -- No it doesn't. Why not try reading and comprehending the answers you have been given? or for that matter reading the C Standard, which clearly and plainly defines the value of `p` in `*p++` to be the value before being incremented, *regardless of when it is incremented*. And don't laugh at Steve's valid comment.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, "Please believe Shahbaz" hahahaha :) A good one!

Comment: The key word is `side effect` here. Please see my comment to the OP.

Answer (score 6):

The lexical grouping is irrelevant. What matters is the **value** of `p++`.

The statement is identical to the following two statements:

```
sum = sum * 10 - '0' + (*p = getchar());
++p;
```

Comment: I still don't understand why the following does not happen: 1) evaluate p++ 2) evaluate getchar() 3) assign the returned value to the now incremented p pointer. When does the postfix increment occur?

Comment: @Vorac You were just told. It doesn't matter *when* p++ occurs ... that doesn't affect the *value* of `p` in `*p` ... that value is, by definition, the value of `p` before the increment occurs.

Comment: @Vorac: evaluating `p++` gives the exact same value as evaluating `p` (only `p++` is an rvalue, while `p` is an lvalue).

Answer (score 3):

```
sum = (((sum * 10) - '0') + ((*(p++)) = (getchar())));
```

is equivalent to

```
*p = getchar();
sum = ( ((sum * 10) - '0') + *p );
p++;
```

it was reduced to 1 line. and it's not useless because writing code in such way will allow to reduce the size and the complexity of your code

```
sum = (((sum * 10) - '0') + ((*(++p)) = (getchar())));
```

is equivalent to

```
p++;
*p = getchar();
sum = ( ((sum * 10) - '0') + *p );
```

Comment: Can't say "equivalent" when there are two `getchar()` calls

Comment: we can't say it's always true.

Comment: What the heck is with those two comments and the downvotes? There's only one `getchar()` call, and we can say that these are always equivalent because the C standard says they are.

Answer (score 0):

Using -- and ++ for pointer assignments isn´t actually useless. Consider a loop where you want to read 10 characters and add the escape character at the end:

```
int i, sum;
char * p;
p = (char*) malloc(11 * sizeof(char));

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   sum = sum * 10 - '0' + (*p++ = getchar());
}
*p = '\0';
```

Comment: What's a bucle? Anyway, this doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: @JimBalter bucle = loop (language issue, sorry). And at the end of his post, he said: "So this syntax is useless. And, pretty much, ++ and -- for pointer assignment is useless. Right?"

Comment: In order not to lose p for future use you could add `for(; sum; sum/=10) { p--;}` after the `*p = '\0';` ;-) Which would fail for the `(sum%10 == 0)` case ...

Comment: It doesn't address the OP's reasons for thinking that it's useless ... that's what this is all about.