# Confusing answers : One says *myptr++ increments pointer first,other says *p++ dereferences old pointer value

Tags: c, pointers, expression, operator-precedence, sequence-points

I would appreciate if you clarify this for me.Here are two recent questions with their accepted answers:

**1)** [What is the difference between *myptr++ and *(myptr++) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262196/what-is-the-difference-between-myptr-and-myptr-in-c)

**2)** [Yet another sequence point query: how does *p++ = getchar() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275813/yet-another-sequence-point-query-how-does-p-getchar-work)

The accepted answer for the first question,concise and easily to understand states that since `++` has higher precedence than `*`, the increment to the pointer `myptr` is done first and then it is dereferenced.I even checked that out on the compiler and verified it.

But the accepted answer to the second question  posted minutes before has left me confused.

It says in clear terms that in `*p++`  strictly the old address of `p` is dereferenced. I have little reason to question the correctness of a top-rated answer of the second question, but frankly I feel it contradicts the first question's answer by user `H2CO3`.So can anyone explain in plain and simple English what the second question's answer mean and how come `*p++` dereferences the old value of `p` in the second question.Isn't `p` supposed to be incremented first as `++` has higher precedence?How on earth can the older address be dereferenced in `*p++`Thanks.

Comment: “The accepted answer for the first question [...] states that since ++ has higher precedence than *, the increment to the pointer myptr is done first and then it is dereferenced.” Where does it say that?

Comment: @PascalCuoq If in `*myptr++` the `++` has higher precedence, then isn't it obvious `myptr` will increment first and then dereferenced?

Comment: When `x++` is not directly enclosed between sequence points (say `2 + 3 + *p + x++`), you do not know **when** `x` is incremented. It can be anytime between the previous sequence point and the next sequence point, regardless of precedence. But you cannot observe the difference anyway because it is forbidden to to write to or to read from `x` elsewhere between the same sequence points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postfix increment operator does have [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator, but postfix increment on a variable returns the value of that variable *prior to* incrementing.

```
*myptr++
```

Thus the increment operation has higher precedence, but the dereferencing is done on the value returned by the increment, which is the previous value of `myptr`.

---

The answer in the first question you've linked to is not wrong, he's answering a different question.

There is no difference between `*myptr++` and `*(myptr++)` because in both cases the increment is done first, and then the previous value of `myptr` is dereferenced.

Comment: Thanks.You made clear a very crucial nuance that I had missed this long.

Answer (score 1):

> The accepted answer for the first question,concise and easily to understand states that since `++` has higher precedence than `*`,

Right. That is correct.

> the increment to the pointer `myptr` is done first and then it is dereferenced.

It doesn't say that. Precedence determines the grouping of the subexpressions, but not the order of evaluation.

That the precedence of `++` is higher than the precedence of the indirection `*` says that

```
*myptr++
```

is exactly the same (not on the cource code level, of course) as

```
*(myptr++)
```

and that means that the indirection is applied to the result of the

```
myptr++
```

subexpression, the old value of `myptr`, whereas `(*myptr)++` would apply the increment operator to what `myptr` points to.

The result of a postfix increment is the old value of the operand, so

```
*myptr++ = something;
```

has the same effect as

```
*myptr = something;
myptr++;
```

When the side-effect of storing the incremented value of `myptr` happens is unspecified. It may happen before the indirection is evaluated, or after that, that is up to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Section 6.5.2.4 of the C specification discusses the postfix increment and decrement operators. And the second paragraph there pretty much answers your question:

> The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the
>   value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
>   added to it).
>   
> ...
>   The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of
>   updating the stored value of the operand.

So given `*myptr++`, yes it's true the the `++` part has higher precedence; but precedence does not exclusively determine your result. The language defines that with the specs. In this case the value of `myptr` is returned, then the "side effect" of `myptr` being incremented is executed.