# Increment the content of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

If `x` and `y` are pointers to the same variable variable,
what does `*x++=*y++` mean?

```
int a,*x,*y;
*x++=*y++;
```

I expected an error but it didn't

Comment: ***If*** `*x` and `*y` point to the same variable then `*x = *y` has no effect. But `*x++ = *y++` increments both pointers afterwards.

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve] ... from the code shown, `x` and `y` are uninitialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusing answers : One says \*myptr++ increments pointer first,other says \*p++ dereferences old pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281872/confusing-answers-one-says-myptr-increments-pointer-first-other-says-p-d)

Comment: It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @rsp probably not, as by the text ... but yes, **only** the code lines shown here would be undefined.

Comment: You _could_ get an error because in your example x and y have not been initialized. Should they point to memory outrside your assigned memory, you get a segmentation fault. Or you get an error (or seg fault) if this has changed another variable the program relies on. Or...this is so-called _undefined behavior_ because now anything can happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression is similar to

```
*x = *y;
x++;
y++;
```

The operators you see in `*x++ = *y++` will be evaluated with regard to the [C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) rules. The increment `++` operator has a higher precedence than the dereference `*`, *but* since we have a post-increment the operations will be carried out *after* the assignment.

Comment: Is it about the priority of the operators?

Comment: @HiruniNimanthi I added an explanation regarding the precedence evaluation.

Comment: Note there's no such thing as *operator precedence* in C. There's only a grammar that allows to deduce a precedence order, but with some limitations. Apart from that, correct, `*x++` is equivalent to `*(x++)`.